# ul and li styles should come to right side

Tags: html, css

below is the given fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Fx9rA/

```
<div id="wrap">

        <ul id="accordion">
            <li>
                <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul id="accord">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="history_heading" rel="history_heading">HISTORY</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="geography_heading" rel="geography_heading">GEOGRAPHY</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>FOIS</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>ASP</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>PTT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    Consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My problem is when i mouse hover the first tab i.e CMT then the block which displays containing history and geography lists are coming to right side but i want it to the left side.I don't know wheres the problem also i know very little of css. Please help me

```
#wrap {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
}


#accordion {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    #accordion h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
        color: #333;
        background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        #accordion h2:hover {
            background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
            color: white;
        }

    #accordion li div.content {
        display: none;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #f6f7e7;
        /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    }

    #accordion li:hover div.content {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        display: inherit;
    }

    #accordion li:hover h2 {
        color: white;
        background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
        background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
    }

#accord > li {
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    #accord > li > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }


#accord a {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add '0' padding to the ul in the dropdown:

```
 #accord{ padding: 0; }
```

This removes all padding from the list. Browser styles are implemented on most elements and sometimes need to be removed to achieve the results we're looking for.

Try also, applying a 'reset.css' before your style sheet - this will give you a blank canvas to work from : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Like this

just write `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` in your stylesheet and then you got your solution.

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx9rA/4/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
    #accord > li > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;


    }
```

Comment: no i want the history and geography  to be extreme left and their siblings to right of it

Answer (score 0):

You can give your li under History and Geography a class with text-align:right or use padding-left:?px or margin-left:?px. The padding and margin will give you more control over the space you want them to the right.

Comment: The answer I gave is based on the fiddle that Fags posted.